# Chain rule in conditional probability

Tags: probability, markov-chains, bayesian

I'm currently taking a class on computer vision and I have the following problem: I should prove that, if my probability function is given as $p(a,b,c,d)$ and it can be displayed as:

$p(a,b,c,d) = p(a) p(d|b,a) p(c|d) p(b).$

We should show that a and b are independent. ($p(a,b)=p(a){}\cdot{}p(b)$) I manged to use the chain rule to get to some other terms, but I end up with:
$$p(c|d,b,a){}\cdot{}p(d|a,b){}\cdot{}p(a,b)= p(a) p(d|b,a) p(c|d) p(b),$$
so, how can it be that 
$$P(b|d,c,a) = P(c|d).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the statement is not true. It may hold for some models; but in general the only thing you can say is that
$$p(a,b,c,d) =p(a)p(b|a)p(c|a,b)p(d|a,b,c)$$
with any other permutation of the variables also valid.

If you set as an assumption that
$$p(a,b,c,d) =p(a)p(b)p(c|d)p(d|a,b),$$
Then, we can integrate out (marginalize out) the variables $d$ and $c$ in both expressions and we get that
$$p(a)p(b|a) = p(a)p(b),$$
which means that (if the given factorization holds) then $a$ and $b$ are independent.

Comment: thank you, can you tell me what integrating/marginalizing out in this context means? I was looking for rules on how to drop terms, but I couldn't get that far, I seem to be missing the step inbetween.

Comment: The law of total probability says that $\int p(a)\mathrm d a = 1$,  so if we integrate wrt $d$, $p(d|a,b)$ adds up to 1 and disappears. The same holds for $p(c|,d)$ when integrated wrt $c$.